# Задание первой недели CS50 с пирамидками в игре "Марио"

Tags: c, cs50

Начала выполнять задание первой недели курса CS50. Вполне ожидаемо появились проблемы :))) Прогнала фрагмент кода до do-while loop - всё работает. Но вот с оставшейся половиной видимо что-то не так.

Выдаёт 2 ошибки:

1. > more '%' conversions than data arguments
2. > expected identifier or '('.

Буду безумно рада, если кто-нибудь поможет разобраться!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char c, int n);

int main()
{
    int n; 
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    } while (n < 1 || n > 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf(' ', n-1-i);
        printf('#', i+1);
        printf(' ', 2);
        printf('#', i+1);

        print('\n',1);
    
    }
}

void print(char c, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: Терзают меня смутные сомнения в том, что в C иметь две функции с одним именем (`printf`) нельзя. Как и не стоит передавать строку вместо `char`...

Comment: и правильно терзают:)

Comment: @Harry,  а разве мы не должны при этом получить две перегруженные функции? Или перегрузка есть только в С++?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov https://stackoverflow.com/q/479207/13970074

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Увы, перегрузка из С и С++ есть только в С++ (допускаю ее наличие и в каких-то иных языках, но не в С...)

Comment: в новых си есть хитрая система с макросами, которую теоретически (ещё раз, сильно теоретически) можно считать перегрузкой.

Answer (score 1):

В коде Вы добавили свою функцию `void printf(char c, int n);`, функция с подобным названием уже есть. Это во первых. Замените ее имя на что то другое. Например, просто print.

Дальше, Ваша функция printf принимает первый параметр char, а Вы ей подсовываете строку. Упс.

То, что в двойных кавычках - это си строка (массив символов). Что в одинарных - символ (`char`). Если в двойных кавычках один символ, это все равно строка (там ещё есть нулевой символ.

Поэтому, вместо

```
printf(" ", n-1-i);
```

надо писать

```
printf(' ', n-1-i);
```

А в конце вообще вызываете с одним параметром. Скорее всего там нужно 1 передать вторым параметром.

```
printf('\n',1); // очевидно, здесь будет Ваше новое имя
```

и после этого все вдруг начинает работать магическим образом.

Вот мой вариант, что бы не было разногласий

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char c, int n);

int main()
{
    int n; 
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    } while (n < 1 || n > 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        print(' ', n-1-i);
        print('#', i+1);
        print(' ', 2);
        print('#', i+1);

        print('\n',1);
    
    }
}

void print(char c, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень стыдно, но я поняла только первый абзац... Только-только начала погружаться в С, поэтому можете, пожалуйста, подробнее объяснить последние два замечания? "Подсовываете строку", про какую именно строку идёт речь? И каким образом изменить код, чтобы первый параметр передать вторым? Заранее спасибо большое

Comment: Поняла всё кроме "Скорее всего там нужно 1 передать вторым параметром". Знаю, что моё невежество уже начинает порядком раздражать, но можете, если не сложно, расписать этот пункт, так же как про различия в кавычках для строк и символов. Я вроде изменила printf('\n',1); на print('\n',1); , но что-то мне подсказывает, что это далеко не всё, что нужно было сделать. И снова заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: есть только один способ понять, все ли правильно было сделано - скомпилировать и запустить.

Comment: Уже. В том-то и проблема - не запускается.

Comment: добавляйте в вопрос новые ошибки, будем разбирать

Comment: Готово. Что самое интересное, как бы я код не крутила - выдаёт всегда только те две ошибки, о которых я изначально в вопросе писала. Это немного сбивает с толку.

Comment: потому что Вы забыли в коде в цикле поменять printf на print

Comment: Изменила. Всё равно не запускается. Ладно, спасибо вам за помощь большое! Попробую с нуля заново написать, может глаз уже просто замылился и очевидных ошибок не замечает.

Comment: Попробовала прогнать ваш код - работает. Сверила со своим, оказался 1 в 1. В итоге просто скопировала свой код и создала новый файл, в который его вставила. Сразу заработало. Может ли быть такое, что просто случился перегруз(?) того файла, в котором я писала или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: чудес не бывает. Ищите ошибки